How to deal with coauthors who just do a lot of unnecessary work and exploration to be seen as hard-working and grab authorship?
I am a post-bachelor researcher in computational biology.
One of my coauthors is a PhD student. He has many ideas, and is seen as independent, innovative, hardworking, and creative. The problem is most of the stuff that he tried just simply doesn’t make sense. It’s the sort of thing that I don’t even try because I know that it’s going to fail and people are going to ask a lot of questions about it. He proposed a lot of things, tries them, and said that they worked, but when I dig in, he and I can never reproduce his results. When I stated my concerns, the PI was inclined to give the PhD student the benefit of the doubt, and the PhD student insisted everything was fine. And he just kept continuing in this direction further by pursuing and leading a 6-month mini-project which I feel was a huge waste of time.
In the end, the paper was rejected by the reviewers because they were specifically concerned about his ideas and additions. My other colleagues (2 postdocs and 1 master student) also asked questions about his ideas. The PI has finally accepted that these ideas didn't work, and the model is going back to my old model since his additions do not improve the performance at all.
Despite this, he is seen as hard-working and has a lot of ideas, while I am seen as a cynical contrarian. So he was “promoted” to a co-first position and becomes the project leader and I become a third author.
How can I deal with this? I understand he seems to have more ideas and be putting in more effort, but it is a net negative for our group's progress. If they had listened to me, we could have avoided wasting much time and effort working on my colleague's bad ideas. In fact, the delays this has caused have delayed publication, which in turn are delaying my own application to PhD programs (after working in this lab for years, I need some sort of publication to show for it if I am to be competitive).

Did you actually tell anyone, notably the PI, ahead of time that the mini-project would fail? Did you or anyone else tell the PI why the paper was rejected?

@ivicts "In the end, the reviewers said the same thing as me, and my PI started to believe me." Okay, so the situation is settled then? It looks like you (or the situation itself) already dealt with the coauthor. What more are you hoping for?

@MisterMiyagi Before the mini project, the PhD did some "prototype" or quick try and he said it worked better than the baseline. However, I could not reproduce the prototype and he could not reproduce it himself. The baseline is still better. This happens before the mini project, but the PI initially believed him more even when the PhD could not reproduce his own experiment. The PI probably thought I was making things up. However, the PhD still tried to pursue the mini project after the prototype does not even beat the baseline which is a really silly thing. I feel it's a waste of time..

@MisterMiyagi The PI definitely knew why the reviewers rejected the papers as he could also see the reviewers comment in the system. Three out of three reviewers had concerns about some of the PhD's ideas.

If you don't like working with someone and feel the collaboration is not fruitful, then do not work with them.

@Tom Yes, that's the easiest way to do it and my favorite. But, I heard that people say we need to try to work with someone we disagree with or we don't like. So, that's the point of the question. But, in some ways, the PhD is also lying and doing non reproducible research, so it's not only about disagreement, but also crossing ethical boundaries.

I'm not saying this is happening here, but sometimes people over-estimate the extent to which they ''know'' something will not work without trying.  I knew a professor and he said of his best student that he had a tendency to say that something would not work without trying it first, and this is someone that was a good mathematician.  Regarding order of authors, I don't think this especially matters unless you are the lead author or the final author.  Getting annoyed with someone because they got to be ''co-first'' author whereas you ''second co-first'' is probably a waste of time.

I worked in a lab once with someone who would try random pointless stuff which obviously had predictable results and then presented it at lab meetings like they had contributed a lot to impress the clueless PI, so I feel your frustration at the same time.  Just one of those things.

@Tom Yes, I do agree that's what other poster below said. The problem was I have tried a lot of stuff for a year before saying that the model cannot really be improved. And before me, there was another guy also doing the project for a year. We also had manuscript in my first year ready and I thought it's gonna be submitted. The problem is I am not even a cofirst author, I am a second / third author after 3 years of work and the model reverted back to my first year's model. The PhD becomes a cofirst author even when what he tried did not actually improve the model.

@Tom Yes that's precisely what this guy is doing. You know what I mean right? Because some posters below doesn't seem to get what I meant. Then, you just stop collaborating with your labmate? or did you try to find a way to work with him?

@ivicts Yes I know what you mean.  In the end the frustration got too much and I quickly found another job and left. I am not sure what I would have done if I had continued.  I am not saying this is the right thing to do necessarily as I don't know your situation, but I would have just asked to speak to the PI and said I felt that the situation was unfair and explained what was happening.

If it is any consolation I have also had to publish articles in top journals with a co-author on the list of authors who contributed literally nothing.  Although I was annoyed for a while, after a while I just moved on as there was nothing I could do about it.

Note that OP has asked about this situation a few times in the last several months, including here (perfectionist PI) and here (irreproducible results). The latter made it sound like clear research misconduct by the PhD.

@DanielR.Collins Thanks, there are so many moving parts of the whole problems. But, on each question, I try to focus only on one part although the comments are quite unfocused usually.

@Tom Yes, I talked to the PI but the situation also puts the PI into a difficult situation because the PhD is doing more "raw" work even though that the model revert back to the original model. So, this puts the authorship ordering in a grey area because the PhD says that he should be the first author because the first author is determined by the number of exploration not by the "lucky" one who find the working method that is ultimately use in the paper even though I know that his exploration is just plain BS.

@DanielR.Collins seems like the only suggestions that stuck to me is just to stop working with this PhD..

It must be aggravating being more insightful than your advisor.

@a rural reader It certainly is, trust me.

@Aruralreader not to sound arrogant, but some of it comes from trying a lot of stuff and it doesn't work. Then, the PhD tried a similar direction and kept saying that it worked, so I became suspicious. Also, I am the one who does the experiment, if the PhD says something worked, then I can try that idea as well on my code, and sometimes it doesn't align with what he said. The PI won't do this and he just takes everything that the PhD said at face value. Of course, no one assumes that the PhD was misleading before.

FWIW, this all sounds like the underlying issue for the concrete situation is sloppy culture in the group. There are groups in which "it works and is better" is just a throwaway verbal statement, and those in which it is a proper (albeit informal) presentation including hard numbers and/or plots. The latter is much more difficult to fake and get away with.

@MisterMiyagi Actually, there's another detail. So, my PI doesn't want to give us the label for the test set, so that the model can generalize more. It's like a kaggle competition. The PhD kept having better numbers on some metrics on the test set although his validation set is not better than mine. It turns out that his test set is actually easier than mine. The same exact model has a 20% improvement in one metric just by training and testing it on his dataset. So, we are not comparing apple to apple on the test set.

@MisterMiyagi but, if we compare apple to apple on the same dataset, his idea doesn't improve the baseline. The problem is the PhD knows that the dataset was different (I confronted him and he slipped up) because he's the one generating the dataset, but he denied and bluffed it when my PI asked us to check all assumptions. Also, in the end, the PhD also cannot show that what he does improve from the baseline using a hard number, then the idea was discarded after the paper is rejected.

Here's my perspective as a PI. A graduate student or postdoc who is intrinsically curios and wants to explore different avenues, even ones that are potentially low reward because they go against some accepted norms is really great. You never know when you will stumble on a paradigm shifting result. There are many "accepted" ideas out there that are simply wrong, or biased, or based on very limited parameter scope, and some more checking and exploration can open up new areas of research. With experience and maturity, this curiosity will coalesce with their deeper understanding of the science, and build intuition which will focus this exploration.
You choose to view this as "playing the game"... I guess if the game is to perform discovery driven research, then yes, that is "the game". If you think that this is to "look busy" to garner favoritism from a PI, then that is already a significant negative bias on your part.
As for ideas being rejected by a reviewer? Any time you propose something non-standard it will be questioned. Sometimes the reviewer is right, sometimes the reviewer is wrong. That does not make the idea intrinsically wrong, it just may mean it is not ready for publication. Ultimately, this is peer review doing its job. It is flagging something that is either potentially wrong, or needs more proof to be accepted. Most definitely, this is not the sign that one should just stick to established protocol, because that will just lead to mediocre science that doesn't move forward.
It is clear that this is upsetting you, and likely bringing up feelings of envy, but you have to understand that those feelings are on you. So how can you deal with such a person? You can either learn to work with them and put their strengths to use, or you can stop working with them because you see a significant incompatibility. Just be aware, if you pursue a career in research, you will always come up against scenarios where seemingly less "deserving" or "intellectual" colleagues will garner more attention or praise than you. Learn to work through those feelings because they are ultimately self-destructive.

I cannot reproduce his result on the initial direction and he also could not reproduce his result. I kept asking him his code and he didn't want to give me his code. The PI initially believed him because he's hard working and he lets him to do the mini project. I mean, he could not reproduce his own result.. why would he continue in this direction? I feel that the "hard working" is just done to "look busy". The paper was rejected by the reviewers and in the end this idea was discarded because it's not reproducible, doesn't make sense biologically, and doesn't improve the performance.

How can I work with them? I mean if I try all the ideas that come up into my head even when I know that it will not work, I will be "hard-working" and have "a lot of ideas" too. But, if I know it's not gonna work, then it's a waste of time, right? It's gonna be an issue in authorship because he will do a lot of stuff, but in the end, he's also showing that the model cannot be improved which is the same conclusion as what I said 2 years before, so 2 years are wasted... Then, I also need to try things and explore things that I know it's not gonna work just to maintain my authorship.

So you mean, that in the context of research people tried several ideas, then concluded that one of the original ones was better. I've never heard of such tomfoolery. This is certainly not how things are done. It is best to find one idea that works and never explore anything again because there may be a risk that the old idea was indeed better, and that is a risk nobody should ever take. Everyone knows that the cornerstone of research is find one thing that works and never try anything new again.

The problem is the PhD never told us that his idea is not working, he kept saying what he's done is better and did a mini project pursuing that direction further. Yes, there's a risk for everything, but we need to try small stuff and fail fast right? It feels like the PhD didn't tell us this, spend two years and in the end revert back to the original thing. I guess when I have a collaborator pursuing one direction, usually when it doesn't work, they say it doesn't work. This is not what happens with the PhD, we only revert back to the original idea after the reviewer rejected the papers.

Also, I know that exploring thing is good, but sometimes we need to stop and start submitting the papers right? Otherwise, the project will go on and on forever and we never submit the paper. Sometimes, we cannot try everything, and we need to have a deadline to submit the paper. Yes, we work hard, but we need to work smart as well? For the context, the project runs for four years and hasn't been published yet.

If there's a researcher whose approach is perennially nonproductive and you disagree with them, the answer is -- Stop working with them.
In the OP's current case, working for years as a post-bachelor's lab assistant, under a nonproductive PhD student, under a faculty PI: You can just leave today. It sounds like it's not being profitable. A paper with your name on it is not even a requirement to enter graduate school (in my experience and awareness). Just go apply to graduate school now if that's your goal.
Obviously you don't waste time futzing with approaches you know won't work in advance, so as to appear busy. That's a complete non-starter.

The problem is he's seen as "productive" and "hardworking" instead and sometimes he really is hardworking (without the quotation). I feel that what he does is a grey area to be honest because it makes his colleague look bad by keep saying things are working when it's not.

I feel that no publications after 4 years of research puts me in a very difficult situation because people will wonder why I don't have publication after years of work even when I have no say (as someone said I am in the bottom of the pole) when the paper is gonna be submitted. So, it becomes a liability on my application and I am just stuck. I applied for a PhD on my second year, but didn't get in and waiting for the paper to be published, but it never gets submitted.. so even to leave from this situation, I need publications. otherwise I am in a dead end in my academic career..

@ivicts The real solution would have been to not put 4 years into this situation before doing something else. Even perfect advice now can't get you that time back or help you compete with someone who was productive in publications over their last 4 years who is applying to the same PhD program. If you can't get into a PhD program (did you apply broadly, or only to a couple institutions?) then you can pursue a non-academic career, which is the same place that most people who complete a PhD will be once they've finished.

@BryanKrause hindsight is 20/20. During my first four months here, my PI said that we were gonna submit the paper "soon". Then, at the end of the first year, I told him that the model was saturated and very hard to improve, and then he added the PhD student probably thinking that I was lazy. And after two years of trying this and that and the paper got rejected, we reverted back to the similar original model. The problem here is my PI is really a perfectionist as well. When you said "before doing something else", what does this something else entails for example?

@BryanKrause now I am trying to get into another postbac researcher experience with another PI and get publications from that, then see how...

@ivicts Yes, hindsight is 20/20, but you had opportunities for some partial hindsight before it got to 4 years. "Something else"s might be a different project or different advisor.

@BryanKrause Yes, I have asked new project since last year, but I am afraid of the new project becoming 2 - 3 years project again. Most PhDs in our lab only have one first author when they graduate and most extend by one semester or a postdoc, that's the baseline. Also, I have partial hindsight, but I also want to keep my authorship position, knowing that if I change to another projetct, I will get lower authorship position on this project. But, in the end, I got lower anyway because of the PhD.

@BryanKrause Actually I planned to ask the PI for a new project where I can be a first author after this project is ending, but this project is never ending, so that's the problem. In the end, I got a new project last year after I hinted very strongly I want to move on from this project. Otherwise, without hinting, my PI keeps wanting me to do this project. He really likes this project and keep pouring a lot of resources and manpower to this project. At least, I know that I should not do a PhD with my PI, he's very nice, but what he does put people's career in a difficult situation.

Now that it's been 4 years I don't think a new project is the right way to go anymore. When you're on a dead end project and the PI won't let you do anything else it's time for a new PI.

@BryanKrause I guess the PI sees trying stuff and exploring stuff as being hardworking which sometimes I agree, but there should be a deadline to it, otherwise we won't have papers and everyone's burning out. He targets high-impact journals though, like IF 30 or something. Should I tell my PI that 'these days I am concerned with my careers and that I have no publications after 4 years and my best contribution is just a third-author paper? Of course, in a nonblaming way. Or maybe I should not do that and keep trying to find a new PI on my own?

@ivicts I think that would have been a good conversation to start having 4 years ago, and better late than never, but I'd question the wisdom of putting substantially more time into a place that hasn't been productive for you over that time frame. As far as exploring and being hardworking, I do think that if your primary role in the group is showing that other people in the group's work doesn't actually work, it's not surprising you don't have any publications.

Not saying that's not a noble effort and important for science, it's just not something you get documented credit for and shouldn't be your sole activity.

@BryanKrause To be honest, I agree with what you meant, I might go too extreme on that front. I feel that this is the fault of both me and the PhD. If the PhD is a normal collaborator, he would say himself that the things he tried don't work and won't add a lot of stuff to the model. He said that it worked, but I couldn't show that it worked on my code so it becomes me trying to prove that he's wrong. If he acknowledges it himself, we could just debug this together. I don't know what should I do though, should I just get along knowing he added a lot of stuff that doesn't work?

@BryanKrause if I just get along and wait for the paper to be rejected by the reviewers, I would probably get a co-first author by now. On the other hand, I don't want to spend so much time on a paper that I know it's going to be rejected anyway, so I became quite critical about it (it's my fault, I know). I guess the moral of the story is relationships are sometimes more important than being right? Yes, also in my group, there is a PhD who continues to be a postdoc and she hasn't submitted her paper after 5 years of work, so the problem is not only my problem (I know it sounds like excuses).

@BryanKrause I also guess that it became my focus because the PhD denied what I said, so the PI didn't believe me instead and it impacted my credibility as the PI kept cutting me off or mad when I said something didn't work or that the dataset is not consistent. So, it forces me to prove the PhD wrong to gain back my credibility which in turn alienates the PhD as I prove him wrong. Not sure how it can go differently though.

@ivicts Sometimes you have to make your case and move on. If you know a project is broken and the people in charge of it are stubborn about it then it's better to cut your losses and ask to be off the project. You don't need to prove the PhD student wrong, if their work can't be reproduced it's up to them to create reproducible code that demonstrates their result. Proving something can't work is always harder than proving it can.

I think why people are arguing with you is because you have set up an extreme choice and seem to have no sympathy for either the other student or the professor. You seem to be assuming malice rather than incompetence, which is far more likely.
Some of the things you learn as you go along in your career are :

sometimes students are not telling the full truth. It seems like the PI was taken in by the PhD student. That is a lesson, but hardly surprising, given that they probably work mostly on separate things.

how to filter ideas/when to stop pursuing an idea. It is good to pursue new ideas, but there are 2 day ideas, 2 week ideas, and 2 month ideas. You do have to construct check points and ignore the sunk cost fallacy.

not to put all your eggs in one basket.


From your comments, you seem to think you were at the mercy of this other student, and that is why you are so mad. It seems you sat by and waited for the other student (correct me if wrong), yielding 4 years with no paper. But, you did have options. You could have chosen to talk to the PI to get other ideas/projects to fill that time. It is best to learn how to have multiple irons in the fire.

"I think why people are arguing with you is because you have set up an extreme choice and seem to have no sympathy for either the other student or the professor." Can you please elaborate more on this? What can I improve on this? I agree with some of the posters that it is important to explore, but as you said there should be a deadline and we should filter ideas otherwise we will never submit a paper. Honestly, all the three points seem to be learning points for my PI instead of me. I agree with all your three points. Actually, it's the PI, not the student, who don't want to submit the paper.

I waited for the PI to submit the paper, and he kept saying we gonna submit "soon" but never submitted it. Instead, he added this new PhD student instead who promises an improvement when it's not really reproducible. Actually I planned to ask the PI for a new project where I can be a first author after this project is ending, but this project is never ending, so that's the problem. Otherwise, if I have multiple projects at the same time, I could not maintain my authorship position. In the end, I got a new project last year after I hinted very strongly I want to move on from this project.

Otherwise, without hinting, my PI keeps wanting me to do this project. He really likes this project and keep pouring a lot of resources and manpower to this project. Btw, just to have a baseline, most PhDs in our group extend by 1 semester or even some doing a postdoc and graduate with only one first author paper. We are in comp bio + cancer biology lab, so that's the baseline.

I think you are assuming malice and subterfuge rather than natural human incompetence… and we all think slight incompetence is the most likely root of the issue.

If the PhD is honest and incompetent, he would tried a lot of stuff and just say that what he tried doesn't work and discarded it like other normal collaborators do. The problem is he kept saying that it worked, adding a lot of stuff to the models, and got us rejected for no reason because his addition does not even improve the performance in the first place. So, I feel that the whole thing is done just to show off, take credit and grab authorship.

Note that in the prior question by the OP, the description there had all respondents pretty convinced that research malfeasance was occurring.

@DanielR.Collins okay, that is helpful. But based on this question alone I stand by this answer - what we have here is a PhD candidate trying a lot of things and a PI letting them and a rant by a BA student saying he is getting screwed over by not “playing the game” like these scheming others.

@Dawn Yes, the PI is hands off so he doesn't know that what the PhD doing is working. He's generally happy that the PhD does a lot of  things. Although he was mad when the PhD couldn't reproduce his result, saying "What you show here is the same as what ivicts is showing right? (Phd name) we can try a lot of stuff, but it must be logical, okay?" and then he stormed out the room. But, at that time, he believed the PhD so he was mad at me instead and excluded me.

@Dawn Other times, my PI also says that "Last time we did this mini project, we thought it's working, but in the end, you also couldn't show that it beats the baseline right?". Another time, when one of my colleagues pointed the idea doesn't make sense, he said "No, it doesn't make sense. You (the PhD) just fit a noise okay?" Also, I am not a PhD but I worked on this project one year before he came in and the reviewers agree with what I said. But, yeah, the PI generally happy the PhD is "hardworking".

@Dawn Also, the PI is letting the PhD explore things because he thought what the PhD tried is working, but in the end all the things that he tried didn't improve over the baseline.

Sure, it sounds like the PI has stuff to learn to better manage such things. They are probably annoyed too. You should probably apply to PhD programs now to get out of there.

@Dawn I guess it's hard to know this stuff from the PI's perspective because the PhD is also misleading and my PI is hands off. I know a lot of this BS because I am also doing the experiment myself, so if the PhD says something works, I usually try it on my code to see if it also improves my model. Then, my experiment generally doesn't agree with him. Of course, I trust my experiment/numbers more.. so I become suspicious of him..

Yes. You should ask the PI if they would write you a strong letter. Communicate what you think your strengths are. If you apply widely you may be able to do well with a good letter and a good manuscript ready for submission. Although it has been many years, my husband got into a great program with a great letter and no publications.

@Dawn thanks, usually strong letters correlate with publications. Sometimes I wonder if I do research for 4 years with no publication whether I am cut out for a PhD or whether I should just go to industry. Did your husband do it right after undergraduate? I feel that no publications work when you apply right after your undergraduate, if I do research for several years and have no publications, it becomes a red flag instead...

What you describe is not unique to academia. In an ideal world, technical correctness would win every time, but in the real world people are fallible, politics is real, and you can definitely find yourself being sidelined for being the cynical voice of reason, even after your predictions come true again and again. It can be extremely frustrating, but it’s part of life. There are some strategies you can learn to deal with this sort of situation.
First, realize that you aren’t always right, even if you often are. Not saying you’re wrong in the situation you presented, just good to keep in mind going forward. If you’re pretty good at analyzing situations and calling out faulty reasoning, don’t fall into the trap of assuming you will be right all the time—you won’t.
Second, realize that everyone makes mistakes, everyone has strengths and weaknesses, so don’t assume malice without strong evidence that can’t be better explained by incompetence or a simple mistake.
Third, accept that politics is real and necessary to succeeding in the workplace. This doesn’t mean acting dishonestly or otherwise unethically, but it does mean being aware of and cultivating your professional image both outside and inside your team and being aware of the motivators of those on your team, especially your boss. In terms of motivators, a professor generally has significantly more motivation to help a PhD candidate succeed than to help an undergraduate researcher succeed. This may well explain some or all of what you’re experiencing, and it may be unavoidable as long as you remain an undergraduate researcher.
Learning workplace politics also means knowing when to keep your mouth shut, realizing that sometimes being the prophet of doom, no matter how accurate your prognostications may be, will make people not like you. It’s often better to let people try something and fail (as long as it won’t harm someone) than to be seen as a naysayer. There’s a time and place for naysaying, but it can be overdone. Also the lower your rank on a team, the lower view your superiors (in rank) will likely have of your naysaying even if it’s right. This unfortunately can come down to ego—the professor may have trouble admitting to themselves that an undergrad was right and they were wrong. It can also just be based on honestly reasonable assumptions: “I’m a professor with years and years of experience. They’re an undergrad who is totally green. It’s much more likely that I’m right.”
Fourth, realize that there are better and worse teams to work on. Resist the temptation to chase the perfect team because it doesn’t exist, but at the same time remember that you can leave a team if it’s just not working for you and your career goals.

Actually, this advice is spot on. Something that I keep reflecting on myself about the whole situation. I guess my fault in this case is that I became critical & belligerent about the issues that I perceived and I became the naysayers and then got excluded from the team. Although my view was validated by the reviewers, I feel that if I just got along, then I would be a co-first author by now. What should I do actually? Should I just get along even when I know that the ideas don't make sense?

Also, to be fair, "letting people try something and fail" may not work in this case because the PhD kept saying what he did was working until the paper got rejected. Then, I need to give a hard number basically proving that the PhD is wrong/misleading and it alienates him. Also, on another hand, in my first year, I kept saying the model was saturated, and my PI didn't believe me and he added the PhD student instead. After two years, we revert back to the original model. So, letting people fail can take 2 years of work..

Also, before the PI submitted the paper, I kept telling him that this paper going to be rejected because the reviewers going to ask a lot of questions about the PhD's ideas. He submitted it anyway and the reviewers did reject the paper because of it. Afterward, I didn't really want to help the group anymore because I felt that I was never being heard and I didn't want to help people who didn't want to be helped. Is this the correct way to react? Or I am not reacting professionally? Should I just help them after they fail?

Yes, I like working in this group and my PI is very nice, but it puts me in a difficult situation in my career if I don't have publications. I am just stuck without publications.

Also, in this case, it did harm someone because the paper got rejected.. when it doesn't need to be rejected because we can just take out all the PhD's additions without any decrease in performance. But, the PhD was stubborn enough so he didn't want to do it and kept pushing it for submission.

"I became critical & belligerent about the issues that I perceived and I became the naysayers and then got excluded from the team. Although my view was validated by the reviewers, I feel that if I just got along..." these are false dichotomy. You can still be critical but not simply following along, though I agree that it is much harder to do. It's what people usually call being diplomatic or street smart.

By harm I mean physical harm or significant harm of any other kind. Not getting a paper published wouldn’t check that box IMO. Someone losing their job might (I say might b/c sometimes you can’t stop someone from walking off a career cliff).  A whole team losing their jobs would be a significant harm and worth significant naysaying, though even there there’s a time say “I’m not the boss, they are” and accept that the responsibility for success or failure lies with them and you can’t change their mind if they’re unwilling to let it be changed.

If your only option is between naysaying so often you get sidelined, and watching your career get sidelined, then my point number four may come into play. That may be the case here. Your university may differ but from my memory there’s very little incentive for a professor to ever prioritize an undergraduate researcher’s advancement over or even on par with a PhD’s advancement. So you’re automatically going to be quite low in the pecking order no matter how amazing a job you do. It may simply be time to go to grad school. As others said you don’t usually need publications to do so.

Also sometimes you can help the truth of your predictions become evident faster by helping speed the work along, though this doesn’t always work (sometimes you’re strong armed away from the tasks that would let you do this) and it can be risky b/c you could set yourself up to be a convenient scape goat if you turn out to be right. Knowing how to navigate this type of situation is a skill that comes with practice. And like I said, sometimes you can help fix it, sometimes you can’t and you either keep your head down or move on.

One final thing I may add to my answer: take a look at how you’re communicating and maybe read up on learning how to speak persuasively, especially to people who have authority over you. It’s a difficult skill to learn but very important and it may also be in play here. You may be communicating the information accurately but not persuasively. Note that some people will not be persuaded no matter what and I’m not saying that’s your fault. But there is a skill that can be learned to at least improve your odds of success when communicating.

@justhalf "You can still be critical but not simply following along" Can you please tell me how concretely what I should do in this case, especially with someone with little power? If they want to finalize the model that doesn't make sense, then I need to use the model, right? I needed to help write the manuscript, create figures, benchmark for something pointless that I knew going to be rejected and it did get rejected and they rewrote all the stuff after discarding the PhD's additions. So, it's wasting my time as well.

@justhalf I can be diplomatically critical, but in the end, I need to follow along.. Also, besides me, two postdocs, and a master's student also questioned the PhD ideas, and the PI diplomatically asked the PhD to confirm whether it worked. The PhD said, "Yes, it worked". Then, I tried the idea myself on my code and it didn't work. So, a diplomatic way (even not from me) may not work with the PhD.

@bob so basically you are saying that I should get along even when I know they are objectively wrong and wait until the paper gets rejected by the reviewer and then propose a better idea, is it?  Also, what I did was not naysaying before the ideas are tried, but I tried the ideas myself and it didn't work on my code and the PhD also could not reproduce his own result which was known before the submission. And the PhD is still pushing for submission. I guess I care too much about this project, if they want to submit it that way, I should just get along and go that way until it gets rejected.

@bob that's true as well, I could help speed the work until it gets rejected, which would take another year, but I might get my cofirst author. I am just the kind of person who cannot be a "loyal soldier" who can do something that I know is objectively not correct, especially since we are doing science. But, it is an opportunity cost to work on a project that I know is going to fail when I can work on another project that might be successful.

@bob Yeah I agree that I don't communicate correctly and diplomatically as well so I alienate people. I guess I became too much of a contrarian then when the PhD lied saying that things worked when they didn't, my PI believed him instead because I was too critical generally. So, that was my fault as well.

@bob I feel that no publications work when you apply right after your undergraduate, if I do research for several years and have no publications, it becomes a red flag instead...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
